# Sort based on string "weight"

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sorting

I searched on the internet for a sort algorithm which sorts the entries of a table in a "natural" way so `10` is after `1` and so on but I found not one solution which is "the perfect fit".

Now I am working on my own solution to do a sort algorithm. My question is now if it is efficient and applicable to create a number for each string in a table row based on the position of their letters in the abc and the position of this letter in the specific string and then sort by this created number?

Example:

`abc` would be `a = 1; b = 2; c= 3` and then the "weight" for each letter should be higher with the string length:

`a = 1 * 1(pos in str); b = 2 * 2; c = 3 * 3`

so `abc` would be 14 as a number.

I don't want this to be a real natural sort.

I have used libraries and the built in Javascript function ".sort()" but they are not working for strings like `92593c17-5183-4db1-b4bd-d538abb4124b`or `ed06d686-8a04-4ae1-9500-975fb85a49d9` so it is not the right thing for me.

So is it a good way to sort strings by their letter-"weight"?

Comment: Whats about localCompare? http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_localecompare.asp

Comment: This type of sorting is called Lexographical. Might be a jumping off point

Comment: you can pass a comparator function to javascript's standard .sort() which decides if one string is heavier than the other.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this little example with localeCompate():

```js
var s1 = '92593c17-5183-4db1-b4bd-d538abb4124';
var s2 = 'ed06d686-8a04-4ae1-9500-975fb85a49d9';
var s3 = '10';
var s4 = '1';
var s5 = 'a';
var s6 = 4;

$('#1').text(s1 + ' before ' + s2 + ': ' + (s1.toString().localeCompare(s2.toString()) == -1 ? 'yes' : 'no'));
$('#2').text(s2 + ' before ' + s3 + ': ' + (s2.toString().localeCompare(s3.toString()) == -1 ? 'yes' : 'no'));
$('#3').text(s3 + ' before ' + s4 + ': ' + (s3.toString().localeCompare(s4.toString()) == -1 ? 'yes' : 'no'));
$('#4').text(s4 + ' before ' + s5 + ': ' + (s4.toString().localeCompare(s5.toString()) == -1 ? 'yes' : 'no'));
$('#5').text(s5 + ' before ' + s6 + ': ' + (s5.toString().localeCompare(s6.toString()) == -1 ? 'yes' : 'no'));
$('#6').text(s6 + ' before ' + s1 + ': ' + (s6.toString().localeCompare(s1.toString()) == -1 ? 'yes' : 'no'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id='1'></p>
<p id='2'></p>
<p id='3'></p>
<p id='4'></p>
<p id='5'></p>
<p id='6'></p>
```

Comment: Thats no reason for a downvote! Just use toString() for everything! I've modified the code!

Comment: calm down vote-gangster. I have used my solution in combination with the `localeCompare`...